# Best way to add custom action/method of any API call?

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, serilog

I'll explain my use case, but I think it can be generalized as it is mainly a code design question.

So I use serilog for logging in my application. What I want is to check whenever the application actually log something that, if the level of the log is above a maximum one, it force exiting the application (in my case any Error or Fatal logging trigger this) :

```
public static void CheckForceExiting(LogEventLevel level, LogEventLevel maxLevel = MAX_LEVEL_BEFORE_EXIT)
    {
        //level is at most the maximum one, so keep the application running.
        if (level <= maxLevel)
            return;

        //level is above maximum one, so Exit the App.

        //Disable UI interaction
        (Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as Main_VM).IsEnabled = false;
        
        string msg = "An exception was caught !", title = "/!\\ERROR/!\\  ";
        if (level > LogEventLevel.Error)
        {
            msg = "Unhandled exception occured !";
            title = "/!\\FATAL ERROR/!\\  ";
        }

        msg += " Closing SDC now.\n\nYou can find the log in ./Logs folder if needed.";
        title += HelperUtils.AssemblyName.Name + ",  Ver: " + HelperUtils.AssemblyName.Version.ToString();
        
        MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        OnCloseLogging();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

My first, working, attempt was to code a full wrapper of serilog.Log own static class, that, for each logging method on this class, add a call to my above method.

But it doesn't satisfy me to just somewhat copy/paste serilog.Log class to just add in any of their logging method a call to `CheckForceExiting()`.

So, instead, I preferred to use my own custom serilog Sink class, that will just call `CheckForceExiting()` as its "logging" action :

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom <see cref="ILogEventSink"/> Sink class
/// that perform/call <see cref="LoggingUtils.CheckForceExiting(LogEventLevel, LogEventLevel)"/> check on each logging level
/// in order to force exiting the application if level is too high (default is Error or Fatal).
/// </summary>
class CheckLevelSink : ILogEventSink
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public CheckLevelSink()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform custom "logging".
    /// Here we are just calling <see cref="LoggingUtils.CheckForceExiting(LogEventLevel, LogEventLevel)"/>
    /// to force exiting the application if <paramref name="logEvent"/> level is above maximum allowed level
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEvent">The logEvent to "log". Here onluy check its level to force exiting the application or not.</param>
    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        LoggingUtils.CheckForceExiting(logEvent.Level);
    }
}
```

And add this sink to the "chained logging" in serilog configuration :

```
/// <summary>
/// Creating a generic host to allow the creation and use of a Serilog logger
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The generic host created</returns>
public static IHost CreateHostBuilder()
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseSerilog((host, loggerConfig) =>
        {
            loggerConfig.WriteTo.File("Logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .MinimumLevel.Information();
            loggerConfig.WriteTo.CheckLevel();
            #if DEBUG
            loggerConfig.WriteTo.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug();
            #endif
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {

        })
        .Build();
}

/// <summary>
/// Extension method pattern to allow an easy way to add the custom <see cref="CheckLevelSink"/> Sink in a <see cref="LoggerConfiguration"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sinkConfiguration">The Sink configuration in which to "add" our custom <see cref="CheckLevelSink"/></param>
/// <param name="restrictedToMinimumLevel">The minimum <see cref="LogEventLevel"/> log level from which we allow logging in the <see cref="CheckLevelSink"/> Sink.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="LoggerConfiguration"/> configuration of the logger that have "added" the custom <see cref="CheckLevelSink"/> Sink.</returns>
public static LoggerConfiguration CheckLevel(
          this LoggerSinkConfiguration sinkConfiguration,
          LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error)
{
    return sinkConfiguration.Sink(new CheckLevelSink(), restrictedToMinimumLevel);
}
```

OK, I found it better, but still seems a little overkill no ?

So, in a more generalized way, whenever you call an external API method and you want to automatically add your custom logic on top (before and/or after) of the API own logic, what is the best practice ?

(Note: I envisaged to use inheritance to serilog File.Write method, but it is a sealed class. So I'm not sure inheritance is a generalized applicable solution).

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what is the added value of this machinery. A simple logging function that exits in case of a severe error seems enough.

Comment: Are you saying that if the error is severe you want the application to stop running? If you want the application to do something when an error happens that's one thing, but I definitely wouldn't use the logger to do it. At that point the logger is no longer just logging - it becomes part of the logic of the application.

Comment: Well I use my personal case to show the problematic of mine, but think outside of logging.
If my application call any given API, which have N methods for example. 
And I want that, each time I call one of the K method of this API (1 <= K <= N), I also add my own, and same, custom logic to this API logic. What is the good practice design to do this ? (Given the fact I have 0 control over how the API is implemented) ?

Comment: And I also answer for my use case : I agree, and that's why it tickle me and make me ask here in a first place, that "hijacking" a logging lib to perform a critical exit of the application anytime any severe error or any unhanded error happen is not the good way to go.
It is convenient as I take advantage of the extensibility of serilog to add my custom logic to exit my application.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust : it kind of what I was doing with my first attempt with a whole wrapper of serilog.Log static class. But it is too much coupled with that class then. I have to redo it for (almost) each of serilog [methods](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Log.cs). I also tried to have an unique generalized method like `Do_Logging(Action logger){ logger(); CheckForceExiting(??); }` called somewhat like this : `Do_Logging(()=>Log.Warning("msg"));` but didn't find out a clean way to get the LogEventLevel from the `Action`.